# How to design layout With animation

Tags: android, android-layout, slider

I need to design layout like image below and also I want such that when I press the button which is on top of image to slide up this layout having images.

[image]

Comment: with Bottom Sheets

Comment: Did you tried any code? If so, please post it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by *implementing bottom sheets*.
I am giving you a perfect link for all types of bottom sheet examples, follow it you'll get the result.
[**Bottom Sheets**](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-sheet/)

Comment: Thank you so much I found what I want exactly